# Software Testing: checking Object Data in RAM is the same after Software changes

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd

I'm in the process of writing tests for a software. The aim of the tests is that when changes are made to the software source no side effects occur.

The software reads data from files and stores them in RAM.

I've written a JUnit test that stores Object Field Values (primitive Types and `String`s) into a `Vector`. These Field Values come from a clearly defined, representative data set in the testing environment. I then deserialize the Vector from my last test run and compare it to current Vector. I then assert:

```
assertArrayEquals(expectedVector.toArray(),actualVector.toArray());
```

like this, I quickly see if data is being stored differently in RAM.

Is this a useful test? 
Is there a more simple approach to test that the Object Data is being loaded the same way?
Is this common practice or are these kinds of tests done in a different manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common practice when testing "legacy code". It's known as [golden master](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/02/20/gold-master-testing/).

It's perfectly fine if you want to have a safety net around code that will detect changes in existing behavior. This is a form of an integration test, meaning that it exercises multiple components at once. This also means that the test has the usual drawbacks of integration tests (slower than unit tests since you're hitting real dependencies like filesystem, network, etc.).

While providing a basic regression check, this kind of test will not tell you where exactly the problem lies. Once you placed an integration test around the code, you could consider to place finer-grained unit tests around the individual components that will allow you to more easily locate problems in the code.

The approach of first "pinning" the codebase with integration tests and then safely refactoring and introducing unit tests is discussed in length by [J.B. Rainsberger](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2014/09/28/surviving-legacy-code-with-golden-master-and-sampling/).

If all you want is this basic regression check and don't care for the benefits of unit tests, you're "golden"!